# How to get notification on my android/ios phone via Chrome's notification?

Tags: google-chrome, android, google-chrome-extensions, notifications, ios

I'm using the Chrome browser on my PC to monitor website/page changes.  I set it up so whenever there's a change on the page, the Chrome browser will notify me via a pop-up notification.

Sometimes I'm away from my computer but I would still like to know when a notification triggers.

Is there a way to leverage this and have that pop-up notification trigger/push a notification on my Android or iOS phone?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for this kind of feature too. Basically, what you are looking for is "Reversed [Pushbullet](https://pushbullet.com)", in which you get push notification on mobile device if there is an activity on your desktop browser. Unfortunately no new discussion related to this, the latest is from 5 years ago: https://www.reddit.com/r/PushBullet/comments/3f59zn/reverse_notifications/

Currently I am still searching for this solution too, but if your service supports IFTTT, you might be able to setup an [SMS notification](https://ifttt.com/sms) by the trigger of your website monitor service.

EDIT: [IFTTT Pushover](https://pushover.net) integration looks promising, the Pushover app itself is pretty cheap